# Looking for sql to find a list of people in a database who don't have a particular row without using not exists

Tags: sql, sybase, subquery

It's easy to find all the users ids who have trait.color = "green" but I need to find all the people who don't.
The obvious way is a subselect for all the ids where not exists (select id where trait.color = "green')
but I was trying to think if there's a way to do it without a subselect.
Is there some trick I don't know about?

sybase 12.5
No foreign keys, but the table is a one to many relationship.
Just imagine a simple

```
ID   trait
--   -----
1    yellow
1    green
1    blue
2    yellow
2    blue
2    black
3    yellow
3    green
3    black
```

Comment: The database (incl version) and table structure would be helpful.

Comment: This can go a couple of ways depending on your relationships. Can you post PK and FK information?

Comment: sybase 12.5
No foreign keys, but the table is a one to many relationship.
Just imagine a simple table as I just added to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NOT EXISTS is most efficient on SQL Server... just do it :-)

```
...MyTable M where not exists (
   select id FROM trait T where T.color = 'green' AND T.key = M.key)
```

Comment: I figured as much. Every once in a while I learn a neat sql trick and thought maybe there was one for this situation.

Comment: @stu: NOT EXISTS *is* the neat sql trick.. most reliable and efficient

Answer (score 2):

If the User table has a one-to-many relationship with the Traits table then the `NOT EXISTS` is most likely your best answer.

You can also try a distinct clause with a left join and trait.userid = NULL

```
SELECT Distinct Users.UserId
FROM USERS
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Traits Where Color = 'GREEN') GreenTraits
        ON Users.UserId = GreenTraits.UserId
WHERE 1=1
AND GreenTraits.UserId = NULL
```

Comment: Interesting, but that's basically functionally equivalent to not exists, no?

Comment: @stu: your question says "without using NOT EXISTS". well, there you go. :)

Answer (score -1):

Join on the UserID where trait.color <> "green"?

Comment: That won't work with his dataset as there are multiple records with the same userid.